# Como adicionar valores no excel em python

Tags: python

Boa tarde, estou tentando adicionar valores em planilha excel que é criando dentro do programa, o problema é que quando o loop volta, ele não adiciona mas sim ele substitui o que já estava no arquivo.

```
    # 1. Responsável Técnico
tab = driver.find_element_by_id('tab_profissional')
dados1 = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('b')
tabela.append(art)
for box in dados1: tabela.append(box.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(tabela).T
df.columns = ['ART', 'Nome Responsavel', 'Título profissional', 'RNP', 'Registro', 'Empresa contratada']


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Responsável Técnico.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Planilha', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Eu até tinha conseguido de outra forma, ele simplesmente ficava tudo na mesma linha.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir o modo como append`(mode='a')`

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Responsável Técnico.xlsx', mode='a')
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Planilha', index=False)
        writer.save()
```